# Can't display the json data which I got from my woocommerce store to another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I want to post the detail of woocommerce orders like id, address, name etc of my woocomerce website to a page of another website of mine. I am getting responses in http://www.baruipurjn.in/wp-json/wc/v2/orders. I want to post the order details. I have successfully included the jQuery file in my functions.php file. My jQuery code is here. I am completely new in json and jquery. Please help.

```
    jQuery(function($){ 
     $.getJSON( "http://www.baruipurjn.in/wp-json/wc/v2/orders", function(data) {
     var ordersData='';
     $.each(data, function(key,value){
        ordersData += "<tr>";
        ordersData += "<td>" + value.id + "</td>";
        ordersData += "<td>" + value.number + "</td>";
        ordersData += "<td>" + value.total + "</td>";
        ordersData += "</tr>";
         });
         $("orders").append(ordersData);
       });
     });
```

The id of the table where I want to put the data is "orders"

Comment: You should store the data in a database, so you can get it from your other website.

Comment: How can I save it to database? Please help. I am newbie